# Can I release stale allocated GRES on a Slurm node?

Tags: slurm

Is there any way to clear stale allocated GRES in Slurm?

I have one node where 4 GPUs are allocated while no jobs are running on the node. Rebooting the node does not release the GPUs.

```
user@control1:~$ scontrol show node node2
NodeName=node2 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=64
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=256 CPULoad=0.05
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:tesla:8
   NodeAddr=node2 NodeHostName=node2 Version=21.08.5
   OS=Linux 5.15.0-83-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 09:30:42 UTC 2023
   RealMemory=1025596 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=1025887 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=DEFAULT
   BootTime=2023-09-19T12:58:23 SlurmdStartTime=2023-09-19T12:59:06
   LastBusyTime=2023-09-19T12:59:07
   CfgTRES=cpu=256,mem=1025596M,billing=256,gres/gpu=8,gres/gpu:tesla=8
   AllocTRES=gres/gpu=4
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s

user@control1:~$ squeue -w node2 --state=all
   JOBID     NAME     USER    STATE         TIME        QOS PRIORITY   TIME_LIMIT NODELIST(REASON)
```

---

The problem reoccurred, this time the shutdown time did not remove the allocation. I removed the acceptance from my answer since it doesn't seem to be the "solution".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this morning the allocation was gone. The node was turned off over the night to conserve energy (clusterwide configuration), apart from that I didn't change anything in the configuration.

```
user@control1:~$ scontrol show node node2
NodeName=node2 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=64
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=256 CPULoad=0.62
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:tesla:8
   NodeAddr=node2 NodeHostName=node2 Version=21.08.5
   OS=Linux 5.15.0-83-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 09:30:42 UTC 2023
   RealMemory=1025596 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=1025777 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=DEFAULT
   BootTime=2023-09-20T07:02:31 SlurmdStartTime=2023-09-20T07:03:14
   LastBusyTime=2023-09-20T07:09:02
   CfgTRES=cpu=256,mem=1025596M,billing=256,gres/gpu=8,gres/gpu:tesla=8
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```